# Formal proof of limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

By using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, prove that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{3}{x^2}=3$$

Here is what I have tried.

$$|\frac{3}{x^2}-3|=3|\frac{1}{x^2}-1|=3|\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}|=3\frac{|x-1||x+1|}{x^2}$$

So I have problem with how to elimate the denominator.

Comment: You want to put a bound on the term $3|x+1|/x^2$ so you can then easily choose a $\delta$ given $\epsilon$. To do that, bound $x$ near $1$, for example $|x-1| < 1/2$. Then generate as crude upper bound for $3|x+1|/x^2$ as you like, so long as it's finite. Call it $M$. I.e., $|3/x^2 - 3| < M|x-1|$. Then given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \min(1/2, \epsilon/M)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \text{min}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{30}\right) \to |1|-|x| < |1-x|=|x-1| < \delta < \dfrac{1}{2} \to |x| > \dfrac{1}{2}$, and $|x+1| = |x-1+2| < |x-1|+|2| < \delta + 2 < \dfrac{1}{2} + 2 = \dfrac{5}{2} \to \left|\dfrac{3}{x^2} - 3\right| < 3\cdot |x-1|\cdot \dfrac{5}{2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}=30|x-1|< \epsilon$

Answer (score -1):

Since $x$ is close to $1$ then $1/x^2 < 4$ and $|x+1|<3$.

Comment: Don't understand why would anybody down vote the reply, but I guess this forum is no different from other. At least they should point out the mistake. The OP asked how to eliminate denominator, which is exactly what I did.