# $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow1}\left(\frac{3}{x^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I am writing a question referring to another question [Formal proof of limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083599/formal-proof-of-limit). The accepted solution posed to this question takes $\delta<\min{\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\varepsilon}{30}\right)}$ but could we in fact take $\delta=\min{\left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{\varepsilon}{12}\right)}$ and anything similar?

Suppose we are given $\varepsilon>0$ then we choose $\delta=\min{\left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{\varepsilon}{12}\right)}$, then $$|x-1|=|1-x|\ge|1|-|x| = 1 - |x| \implies |x|\ge\frac{3}{4}.$$ Also $$|x+1| = |x-1+2|\le|x-1|+2<\delta+2\le\frac{9}{4}.$$ So $$\left|\frac{3}{x^{2}}-3\right| = \frac{3|1-x^{2}|}{|x^{2}|} = \frac{3|x-1||x+1|}{|x^2|} \le \frac{3|x-1|\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)}{\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{2}} = 12|x-1| < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: Sure, whatever works. I wasn't crazy about the given answer to the original question because it didn't show how it was arrived at. I was trying to show my earlier comment how you develop such an argument.

Comment: looks fine to me. by definition, given $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\cdots$. you can have several choice of $\delta > 0$ for a given $\epsilon > 0$ and you can choose any of them.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot both of you.

Comment: This looks good; I think you just want to change $\delta+2=\frac{9}{4}$ to $\delta+2\le\frac{9}{4}$.

Comment: @user2850514: you need to be little more careful about the inequalities. A lot of them are actually "$\leq$", instead of just "$<$". but it didn't matter at the end. but still $\cdots.$

Comment: @Krish I have changed the inequalities that I believe to be incorrect, can you double check these?

Comment: yeah fine. the last inequality is also not strict. but it doesn't matter. if you insist to be more precise, then you can choose $\delta<\min{\left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{\varepsilon}{12}\right)}.$ but as I said before, it doesn't matter.